# NSPredicate subquery over all values of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an object with the following layout:

```
@interface Contact : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *emails;
@end
```

As you can see the emails are modeled by a dictionary with keys which are the email tag and values for the emails themselves (i.e. @{@"home" : @me@home.com"}).

I'm trying to filter a bunch of these by partial match on either username or an email out of potentially many emails each contact might have. But the email subquery is not returning any matches, even if I type in an exact email. I'm not sure where am I messing up the query.

My query looks like this:

```
NSPredicate *userName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.username contains[cd] %@", self.searchFieldText];
NSPredicate *email = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(self.emails.allValues, $x, $x contains[cd] %@).@count > 0", self.searchFieldText];
self.activeFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[userName,email]];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My belief is you're missing an at-sign: `emails.allValues` -> `emails.@allValues`

```
NSPredicate *userName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username contains[cd] %@", self.searchFieldText];
NSPredicate *email = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(emails.@allValues, $x, $x contains[cd] %@).@count > 0", self.searchFieldText];
self.activeFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[userName, email]];
```

A little testing indicates that it should work once that's fixed.